# Update main dictionary inside foreach loop

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I have a Dictionary of `<string, List<ESelectionData>>` and in foreach loop I am iterating through each values in that dictionary.

So what I want is inside foreach loop, some values from the list will get removed and I want that to also be removed from the main dictionary.

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<ESelectionData>> keyValuePair in inC.MainDictionary)
{
    // some calculations

    // here there are some values from the list of "keyValuePair" removed
    // so I want to reflect that in the main dictionary "inC.MainDictionary"

    // How can it be done??
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify the dictionary being iterated. Instead, you could create a set of keys to ignore, add keys of "removed" items to it, ignore them as you go, and finally delete them from the dictionary when you are done with the loop:

```
ISet<string> toDelete = new HashSet<string>();
// This example uses LINQ to ignore keys marked for deletion
foreach (var keyValuePair in inC.MainDictionary.Where(p => !toDelete.Contains(p.Key))) {
    if (some_condition) {
        toDelete.Add(anotherKey);
    }
}
foreach (var key in toDelete) {
     inC.MainDictionary.Remove(key);
}
```

In general, you should be very careful with this solution, because the order of iteration on the dictionary is arbitrary, in the sense that the implementation is free to decide in what order to give you the key-value pairs. Since the decision to dele is made while processing one of the other values in the loop, you need to make sure that the values are processed in the order that your algorithm expects.

**EDIT:** (in response to a comment) If your goal is to modify the content of the lists stored inside the main dictionary, you do not need to do anything special: since `List`s are reference objects, any modifications that you make to `keyValuePair.Value` (which is a `List<ESelectionData>` are reflected in the `inC.MainDictionary` automatically, because they reference the same object.

Comment: He doesn't want to remove an item from the *dictionary*, but from the *list* that is a value in the dictionary. And for that he doesn't have to do anything - it's a reference.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar I am not 100% certain about that - lists are reference types, so removing items directly from them is a very straightforward thing - not worth posting a Stack Overflow question. The only task that could give him a problem is removing a key.

Comment: *here there are some values from the list of "keyValuePair" removed* - maybe his code does something weird, but that's what I read from the question. If what I think is the answer, he surely hasn't tried anything before posting. If that is not the answer, the question should be closed for *not enough detail*.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question you're doing something like this

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<ESelectionData>> keyValuePair in inC.MainDictionary)
{
    keyValuePair.Value.Remove(...);
}
```

You don't have to do anything special for this it will be removed from `inC.MainDictionary` . Since `List<ESelectionData>` is a reference type you're actually modifying the same object.

You can refer here for [value type vs reference type](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx)

Comment: @VishalSuthar If this is the answer, I'll downvote your question: did you even try anything before posting?

Answer (score 0):

Each value of your dictionary is a List itself, so if (you maybe?) want to update the individual ESelectionData objects, you'd need a nested foreach in order to iterate over the properties in each ESelectionData object.

A second thing is the removal of a dictionary entry: you cannot delete a dictionary entry while iterating it with foreach. Instead, you should copy dictionary and remove the corresponding entries from it rather than from your original one.